# Title in ToC is Overwritten

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

In memoir class I define
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\large\upshape\bfseries\color{bleudefrance!80}}{ЧАСТИНА,,\arabic{section}.}{0.5em}{}

and

\renewcommand\thesection{ЧАСТИНА.\arabic{section}~}

In the text of the document this works, each section is numbered "ЧАСТИНА No. TEXT"
But in the Toc "TEXT" overwrites "ЧАСТИНА No." it seems that there is a predefined length for the title in Toc smaller than "ЧАСТИНА No." which I am not able to change

Comment: Instead of two commands and some description, could you turn this into a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497) that specifically shows the problem?  This will save a lot of work for everyone wanting to reproduce your problem.

Comment: As always on this site please post a full minimal example instead, then others can easily copy and test your code and hopefully get an idea of want you want and what is currently wrong

Comment: And don't use titlesec (I assume) with memoir, memoir has its own system and titlesec is not compatible with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven't provided an MWE I can only guess at your problem instead of being able to process your code and see what your problem is.

Your extended section number "ЧАСТИНА No." is longer than the usual "No." so you have to make space for that in the ToC. The normal space allowed for a section number in the ToC is `2.3em`; the following increases it to `6em`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setlength{\cftsectionnumwidth}{6em} % or a more suitable length
...
```

Read section **9.2.2 Typesetting the entries** in the `memoir` manual.

Comment: Thank you Peter this is what I was missing

Comment: @Richard In that case perhaps you would vote up my answer (click on the up arrow).